# Where can I learn to develop an AVL project with ArcGIS javascript Api

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dojo

I  started to develop a   web GIS project   about one years ago.
i need to  show   some cars  on web Pages .
base on i  decided  to use  ArcGis   as  GIS  Server.
  at now  i need  learn  dojo  an  arcGis javascript api.
where  I can start leraning ?

Comment: i think  i  should  ask  this  question in  gis.stackexchange.com..

Answer (score 0):

if  you want  to  develop an  AVL ,you had  to  consider  some  matters.
at  fist you  should  determine location of  your data for example data  of  cars  come form a  socket  or  exist  on a database
base on you  need to setup server side project  to send the  cars data  to client
then  you  must select some client  library.
i suggest you to use the  arc gis javascript api  beacuse it has lots of  samples to show and  animate the elements on map.
therefor  you had to learn  dojo an javascript that  esri provide  a  learning  center  for  that
here  you can find  many samples
[enter link description here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/index.html)